# csv to xls using shell

Tags: bash, shell, sh

Is there a provision for converting csv file to xls using shell scripting ?
Other answers as mentioned below as it shows all the data with a ',' in a single cell of xls.

```
cp test.csv test.xls
```

Comment: Opening csv in excel works find is your csv is valid.

Answer (score 0):

> Other answers as mentioned below as it shows all the data with a ',' in a single cell of xls.

I would say something is wrong with your csv then. I have used csv many a times created via some bash script and it opens properly in the MS Excel as well as in OpenOffice SpreadSheet.

BTW, you don't have to run that `cp` command. Just Open CSV into MS Excel and it will display it properly. MS excel has full support for CSVs.

If you are still facing this issue, then provide sample data to work with.

Comment: CSV file opens well in MS excel.
But my requirement is to generate a .xls file

EX: csv data

    column1,column2
    10,20

I need to create an xls in which
First row, first column ->  column1
First row, second column ->  column2
Second row, first column ->  10
Second row, Second column ->  20

Comment: If it opens fine in Excel, then you can save it as an .xls file. AFAIK, Bash cannot create .xls file. However, you may want to explore [perl](http://homepage.tinet.ie/~jmcnamara/perl/WriteExcel.html) which supports creating .xls files.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `ssconvert` from the [`gnumeric`](http://www.gnumeric.org/) package:

```
ssconvert data.csv data.xlsx
```